# Has anyone _verifiably_ duplicated Yahoo's real time technical market indicators _numbers_? If so, how?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, yahoofinance, technicals

After spending the better part of a week trying to get a combination of Alpaca's API and Python libraries (alpaca_trade_api, pandas and ta) to duplicate the numbers produced by Yahoo! Finance's commonly-used technical market indicators, I've come to the conclusion it's not feasible on that platform, probably due to [relatively stale data from IEX](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/78771/87517).

Has anyone managed to *verifiably** duplicate those indicators with a real time API?

If so, how?

*First, note I'm not *merely* asking about duplicating the numeric algorithms for 
technical market indicators.  I mean the combination of algorithm and data source.  By "verifiably" I mean that, given a stock symbol and a technical indicator, the graphs produced are very nearly the same if not identical.

Comment: I dont know what indicators your are looking for . May be talib will help you https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/

Comment: I mean, Yahoo is free, so you get what you pay for (ie, certainly possible they're wrong)...what is your purpose in trying to replicate them?

Comment: Libraries like 'ta' or 'talib' don't provide the input data.  I have reason to believe Alpaca's market data is frequently stale compared to Yahoo's and thus cannot be used to duplicate Yahoo's indicators.  I want to duplicate those in order to automate a manual, Yahoo-based trading strategy.

Comment: What indicators are you trying to replicate?

Comment: Yahoo! Finance's "commonly-used" technical market indicators with the addition of STOCH.

Comment: Without knowing what "commonly-used" means (I don't use Yahoo), yes I'm able to duplicate a few random indicators. As the question sits, you're unlikely to get any other answer.  You have only asked for a "Yes or No" response..

Comment: Hopefully my clarification to the question suffices.